# Has the rollback option disappeared

Tags: feature-request, specific-question

From the past one week or so, I am unable to see the $\mathsf{rollback}$ option in answers or questions. Has this facility been removed by stackexchange?

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you mean, but you can see edits by clicking on "edited (time) ago" over the name of the editor (as it always was since I'm here). The rollback option is then accessible in the headers of the previous edits. I guess you're particularly interested in [this edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/52123/revisions).

Comment: @Theo: Thanks, I was exactly looking for this. But how do you get to that page.

Comment: @Theo: I don't see a header at all.

Comment: Since you tagged "specific question", I assume you have a specific question in mind?

Comment: As I said, click on "edited (time) ago" above Hendrik's name (that's the link leading to the page I posted) in my last comment. By "header" I meant the bluish blocks starting with "2" and "1" you see there.

Answer (score 2):

This is from an edit I just did of one of my answers. The most recent revision (revision 3) is the one in the blue bar. You go down a bit to revision 2, the previous one, you see on the right of the number 2, the link to rollback.

There's no "rollback" link on the most recent revision, since that is the current one, and there is no point of "rolling back" to something that is already the presented version.

[image]

Comment: Just to note that the colours indicate whether you are the question owner or not. So in my case someone else made the first edit, so revision 2 is gray and revision 3 is blue (my edit). In the link Theo provided, Hendrik's edit is gray (the most recent one).

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.